# Remove namespace from a tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to print certain part of xml in the ouput. But while doing this , namespace is getting appended in the output of the tag. I wish to remove this namespace from output. Please help.

xmltoxslt.xsl file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match = "data">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

input.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:LogDel xmlns:ns0="http://world.com/pi/M/LogDeli">
   <data>
      <ERP>123</ERP>
      <Issuedate>2019-02-18</Issuedate>
      <Shippingpoint>2234</Shippingpoint>
      <Shiptoparty>XXXXXXX</Shiptoparty>
      <products>
         <SKUno>dfsf</SKUno>
         <QTY>50</QTY>
         <Unit>L</Unit>
      </products>
      <products>
         <SKUno>sfsdf</SKUno>
         <QTY>30532</QTY>
         <Unit>KG</Unit>
      </products>
   </data>
   <data>
      <ERP>345</ERP>
      <Issuedate>2019-03-07</Issuedate>
      <Shippingpoint/>
      <Shiptoparty>XXXXXXX</Shiptoparty>
      <products>
         <SKUno>dsfsf</SKUno>
         <QTY>1000</QTY>
         <Unit>L</Unit>
      </products>
      <products>
         <SKUno>sfsdf</SKUno>
         <QTY>300</QTY>
         <Unit>KG</Unit>
      </products>
   </data>
</ns0:LogDeli>
```

InputOuput.xml file:

```
<data xmlns:ns0="http://world.com/pi/M/LogDeli">
     <ERP>123</ERP>
      <Issuedate>2019-02-18</Issuedate>
      <Shippingpoint>2234</Shippingpoint>
      <Shiptoparty>XXXXXXX</Shiptoparty>
      <products>
         <SKUno>dfsf</SKUno>
         <QTY>50</QTY>
         <Unit>L</Unit>
      </products>
      <products>
         <SKUno>sfsdf</SKUno>
         <QTY>30532</QTY>
         <Unit>KG</Unit>
      </products>
   </data>
   <data xmlns:ns0="http://world.com/pi/M/LogDeli">
     <ERP>345</ERP>
      <Issuedate>2019-03-07</Issuedate>
      <Shippingpoint/>
      <Shiptoparty>XXXXXXX</Shiptoparty>
      <products>
         <SKUno>dsfsf</SKUno>
         <QTY>1000</QTY>
         <Unit>L</Unit>
      </products>
      <products>
         <SKUno>sfsdf</SKUno>
         <QTY>300</QTY>
         <Unit>KG</Unit>
      </products>
   </data>
```

I want to remove the namespace `xmlns:ns0="http://world.com/pi/M/LogDeli"` from the data tag. It should be like `<data>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `xmlns:ns0="http://world.com/pi/M/LogDeli"` is present on only the root element in the XML when viewed as text, when this lexical XML is parsed, all descendant elements will also have that declaration stored against them. This means, when you do `xsl:copy-of` then the declarations will also be copied.

What you need to do, is created new elements for `data` and all its descendants.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="data|data//*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On the other hand, if you can use XSLT 2.0, you can make use of `copy-namespaces` on the `xsl:copy-of`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

only following change:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://world.com/pi/M/LogDeli" exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match = "data">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't think `exclude-result-prefixes` will work in this case. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh46

Comment: Hi Ajeet, i tried the change you suggested above. But namespace is still coming after the data tag.